# WPF Converters - Returning the Name of a Class Type

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters

I have a list inside of a list.. and this list is of type "RequirementsBase" (an abstract class).

What I want to do is have the Name property of each item in the list the display in a listbox when an item is selected from the parent list box. (Hopefully that makes sense). Without the converter, when items are displayed in the list box I get the full path namespace of the class. Once I hooked a converter up, it displayed the Name of the list, rather than what is in the list. It is also displaying that name with each letter on its own line within the list box.

Here is my XAML hooking up the converter:

```
<ListBox  Name="lstRequirements"
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listTreasureCards,
              Path=SelectedItem.Requirements,
              Converter={StaticResource RequirementConverter}}"  />
```

Here is the code for my converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
        return value.GetType().Name;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value.GetType();
}
```

I am a noob, so please speak noob. :)

Comment: It's not clear from the question what exactly you want to display. An example would help.

Comment: I want to display the Name property of the types of classes that are in my list. 

So if i were to do:

 List<GameInfo.Requirements.RequirementsBase> mylist (RequirementsBase is an abstract class, so the list actually has items that are of Sex, Level etc)

if I did mylist[0].GetType().Name i would get "Sex". How do I make that show up in my listbox rather than the namespace to it - which is GameInfo.Requirements.Sex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you put the converter on the *list* instead of list *elements*. In order to fix that, you have to add content to the item template (the template that describes how each list box item is shown) and put the converter there:

```
<ListBox Name="lstRequirements"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listTreasureCards,
                               Path=SelectedItem.Requirements">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource 
                                                        RequirementConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're saying is you have an IEnumerable> as your listTreasureCards data source. That would be the list of list of RequirementsBase.

What I believe you want is a flat list of the names of each object (IEnumerable) where each element corresponds to an element of a list of list.

If this is the case, you should try a LINQ expression like the following.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  var typedList = value as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<RequirementsBase>>;
  if (null == typedList) return null;

  return (from list in typedList
          from elem in list
          select elem.GetType().Name);
}
```

Because this is a loss-full algorithm, there is little point in implementing ConvertBack; just throw a NotImplementedException.

Also, just as an aside, the reason that the letters are showing up on different lines is that the ItemSource expects an IEnumerable. Your convert method is returning a single String, which happens to be an IEnumerable (string of letters). So, for this reason, each letter ends up in a different line.

Comment: I had tried to impliment your method, but every time it ran it kept returning null.

Comment: I think this would work if you remove one of the extra `IEnumerable<>`s.

Comment: I had tried that as well.. it didn't work. I did get it to work with another persons solution though.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest most direct way of achieving your goal would be to override `RequirementsBase.ToString`:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return this.GetType().Name;
}
```